# PhpStorm terminal doesn't work properly on Linux Mint

Tags: bash, terminal, phpstorm, linux-mint

My PhpStorm terminal doesn't work properly on Linux Mint

In `Settings > Tools > Terminal` my Shell path is "`/bin/bash`"

When I open Terminal window in PhpStorm and call `ls` command work properly but `php` and `sudo` and etc not work and return `bash: php: command not found`

Original terminal app:
[image: my original terminal work]

Terminal in PhpStorm:
[image: but my terminal window in PhpStorm not work]

PhpStorm CLI interpreters:
[image: my CLI Interpreters]

Answer (score 2):

Does the issue persist if your start PhpStorm from terminal, either with the command line launcher or with `bin/phpstorm.sh`?
When being launched from desktop/System menu, PhpStorm only sees environment variables configured in login shell, but not in interactive shell configuration files (like `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`).
Possible workarounds:

- Workaround 1: make required variables available in a login shell by moving them to the corresponding shell profile config
- Workaround 2: run IDE from a terminal
- Workaround 3: edit the desktop launcher and set command to `/path/to/shell -l -i -c  "/path/to/phpstorm.sh"` (make sure that the shell you specified there has the needed variables configured in its interactive shell configuration file)

see also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7589